# processing.run() returns string instead of QgsVectorLayer with QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition as parameter

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, select, qgsvectorlayer

I try to run `qgis:difference` on selected features of 2 layers. But the result of my code :

```
parameters = {'INPUT': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer1.id(), True),
              'OVERLAY': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(layer2.id(), True),
              'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}
differenced = processing.run('qgis:difference', parameters)
```

is a string `output_...` instead of a QgsVectorLayer as usual.
I have added :

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer1, False)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer2, False)
```

before but the algorithm doesn't work as I want.

Comment: That should be the correct way. How did you define `layer1` and `layer2`?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I run it, maybe it can help

```
diff = processing.runalg("qgis:difference", layer1, layer2, False, None)
result = processing.getObject(diff['OUTPUT'])
# if you want to save it to file
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(result, 'output_layer.shp', "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
```

layer 1 and layer2 are instances of `QgsVectorLayer`